# Converting seconds to hh:mm:ss in XSLT v 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a column which returns the total number of seconds. For example

> 266

I would like to display 266 seconds as

> 00:04:26

This is how I'm doing it in XSLT:

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/CAudioFile/CRI/Duration div 60 mod 60, '00:00:00')"/>
> ```

However, my output is

> 00:00:04

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your math is wrong and '00:00:00' is not a valid format string. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="seconds" select="CAudioFile/CRI/Duration" />

<xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($seconds div 3600), '00')" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($seconds div 60) mod 60, ':00')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($seconds mod 60, ':00')"/>
```

Comment: Michael, although this is working perfectly fine, I want to make a slight change into this. For example, if it's 441 seconds it will display right now as 0:07:21 Is there anyway I can display hours as '00' instead of '0'. The current output is displaying only one zero.

Comment: @user1426542 I believe the solution is obvious: use format-number() on hours the same way it is used on minutes and seconds.